# How to add sorting to a get-aduser powershell script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I use a PowerShell script to return all AD groups a USERID is a member of.  I would like to sort the memberof alphabetically.  How can I do that?

Script I'm using:

```
get-aduser <userid> -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
```

What I've tried:

```
get-aduser <userid> -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | Sort-object memberof
```

Adding Sort-object memberof does not sort it alphabetically...what am i missing?

Comment: Just do `| Sort-Object` at the end. Since you `Expand` the property 'memberOf', you are now dealing with a string array. No mor a set of objects with properties.

Comment: that was the ticket, thank you.  Can you make it an answer so i can give you credit?

Comment: It seems @marsze already beat me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Select-Object` with `-Expand <property>` will return only the values of `<property>`. So when you pipe that to `Sort-Object`, the property doesn't exist anymore.

So you can either change the order, sort by property without expanding first, or expand and then sort the values (without specifying a property):

```
get-aduser <userid> -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | sort
# or
get-aduser <userid> -Properties memberof | sort memberof
# or
get-aduser <userid> -Properties memberof | sort memberof | select -expand memberof
```